# How to create MPK using ArcGIS Runtime WPF?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, map-package

I would like to create a Map PacKage with ArcGIS Runtime WPF.

Have you an example ?

Answer (score 3):

- [**How to create a map package**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#//01700000005t000000) - ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF Help

Or did you mean programmatically? As @KHibma points out, map packages can only be created from Desktop, arcpy or ArcObjects, not the WPF Runtime.

Comment: Yes, programmatically without arcgis desktop. c#

Comment: map packages are created from Desktop. There is no way to create a map package using just runtime components.